# jquery animate disabled after sorted high to low

Tags: jquery, sorting, multidimensional-array, jquery-animate

I have a regular sort that appends items from 'high to low':

```
library.sort(function(a, b) { return a.year - b.year; });
upperlimit = library.length-1

    for (i=upperlimit; i<library.length; i=i-1){
        //source.sort(function(a, b) { return a.year - b.year; });
        item = "<div class='item' style='background-image:url(" + library[i].source + ");' ><h2>" + library[i].title + "</h2></div>"
        $("#list").append(item);
    }
```

But as it is, appending from 'high to low', it somehow disables this other function:

```
    $(".item h2").css({"bottom":"-135px"});

    $(".item").hover(
        function(){
            $(this).find("h2").animate({"bottom":"-85px"},300)
        },
        function(){
            $(this).find("h2").animate({"bottom":"-135px"},150)
        }
    );
```

However, when it is written to append from 'low to high',

```
for(i=0; i<library.length; i=i+1)
```

the animate works fine.

On Firebug, when written for 'high to low', it shows up an error "TypeError: library[i] is undefined" however no errors for 'low to high'.

For both, the everything is displayed properly (image and hidden h2), but it is just the animate that does not function on 'high to low'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> for (i=upperlimit; i<library.length; i=i-1){
> ```

Your high-to-low loop condition is wrong. That's an infinite loop, since `i` starts `library.length-1`, is getting smaller each turn, and will be smaller than `library.length` forever. What you want is

```
for (i=library.length-1; i>=0; i=i-1){
```

When the index goes to `-1`, your current code throws an exception because of accessing a property on `undefined`, and that halts the execution so the event handlers are not attached.

Comment: I see! That works. Great, working at 4am was not smart of me.